# Unity 2019.3.11.f1 + Unity Input System 1.0.0 + Unity Remote 5 + iPhone 8 touch screen not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the new Unity Input System but it does not work with touchscreen.

I found samples repository on GitHub https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem/tree/develop/ExternalSampleProjects/TouchSamples and managed to run samples successfuly using mouse input. OnAction mehtod in PointerInputManager is called for mouse but not called when using iPhone8 touch screen (application is properly displayed on the device using Unity Remote 5). Any ideas how to solve this?

[image: PointerInputManager.cs]

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/new-input-system-and-unity-remote-5.735968/

Input System expected to work with Unity Remote 5 in future.

Comment: i wouldnt hold your breath, didnt they just announce remote is being canned?

Comment: I don't. I just switched to the good, old Input.GetTouch(0) and it works well.